# How to use array variable in PostgreSQL array_append()?

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, yii

I would like to use array variable in PostgreSQL  **array_append()**. If I use array directly then its works but not when using variable.

```
  $name= {1,2,3};
  $Name_key_array={4};
```

I would like to find result by using following way-

```
  $name='array_append(name, $Name_key_array)';
```

or

```
  "SELECT array_append($Books->name, $Name_key_array) as b";
```

Waiting to see some great ideas.

Thanks to all

Comment: it's a wild guess as I can't test it, just try `$name = "[1,2,3]"` and `$Name_key_array = "[4]"`, or `$name = "ARRAY[1,2,3]"`
the idea here is that the array declaration should be in postgresql not php, as for postgresql to understand it. give it a try withing this concept and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

personally, I use json.

```
<?php $json_var = json_encode($array) 
$sql="insert into blah (arr) values (select array_agg(a::text) from json_array_elements(:json_var)";
```